# TFS Permissions - what am I doing wrong?

Tags: c#, vb.net, tfs

I have one collection in TFS 2010 which a user can see even though I haven't given him any rights. I can't figure out why that user can see that collection. He is not a team member for that collection and he doesn't seem to have any specific rights in that collection as seen on the admin TFS website. There are no special groups defined in the collection except the standard TFS groups. What am I doing wrong? How can I troubleshoot this?

Comment: You may want to start by checking which standard Windows groups have access to those TFS groups and if the user is in one of those groups.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The server Administrator gets permission by default in TFS 2010. There may be other domain groups that he is a member of.

It would be a lot easyer to debug if you upgraded your TFS server to the latest version. You are currently 3 major and 8 minor versions behind. In TFS 2012 a way to find effective permissions for a user and trace them to the "why" was added.

Comment: How do you do it in 2012?

Comment: If you find the permission and I says "inherit allow" you can roll over with your mouse and click the "why" button that appears...